# nginx as a reverse proxy for API cannot redirect full url, params, body headers

Tags: node.js, nginx, reverse-proxy

I'am putting my node js API (that I manage with pm2) behind a reverse proxy with nginx, here no problem.

But since, if I send any request it become a GET on '/'.

How can I tell to nginx to forward the full url, the request types (PUT, OPTIONS, DELETE, ...), the requests params and the request body ?

here is my simple nginx config.

```
server {
    listen      80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name api-prod.mysite.com www.api-prod.mysite.com localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3111;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing? your config should send the url and params directly without any modification. Are you using `socket.io` as well? Also add the output of `curl -v http://www.api-prod.mysite.com/<validurl>` in your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your [nginx](http://nginx.org) configuration seems good except, you should use `proxy_http_version` and `proxy_cache_bypass` because sometimes(depends on version) Nginx and nodejs using different HTTP version.

Following configuration working fine for me

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name arifjaunpur.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good answer, you can make a tuto out of this ^^